# How do I merge multiple .net assemblies into a single assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies, merge

I have a .net application with about 10 assemblies. It would be nice to have them all together as a single assembly. How do I do it?

I guess something like a jar file for Java applications.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878807/visual-studio-2008-creating-single-dll-from-solution-with-many-projects

Comment: Thanks @CAD Bloke, that answer provides quite a lot of detail. It was actually asked a week after this one, and foresight doesn't come with the .Net framework yet. :)

Comment: No probs - I (presume - this was a while ago) added the link for visitors later in time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple assemblies into one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge).

NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ILMerge/)

Answer (score 12):

Using ILMerge is probably the simplest solution. However, ILMerge has the drawback that it changes the identity of referenced assemblies. As a consequence, you might run into issues with security or serialization.

[An excellent blog post](http://simoneb.github.io/blog/2011/11/21/past-present-and-future-of-net-assembly-merging/) by Simone Busoli discusses the following options to merge assemblies into a single executable:

1. ILMerge
2. Embedding assemblies as a resource and subscribing to the AssemblyResolve event.
3. Using [**Costura**](https://github.com/Fody/Costura), an open source tool which takes care of embedding referenced assemblies as described in step 2.

Answer (score 9):

ILMerge is the tool you're looking for:

> [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en)

The documentation for ILMerge can be found here:

> http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx