# How to merge multiple assemblies into one?

Tags: c#, assemblies, exe, ilmerge, servicestack

I consuming my service stack using EXE project (startup task for azure application) in that I have copied following service stack's DLL & some Azure's DLLs in to EXE project.

[image: dlls]

When I build this EXE project then Azure DLLs will be bundled with my EXE but service stack's DLL will not be bundled with EXE, because to run my EXE on any machine I need to copy all service stack's DLL manually.

I have used this service stack's dll to use

```
JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient(servicepath);
```

What should I have to do to bundled all these DLLs in to my EXE?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You have several options:

- use [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge) (free)
  For howto see [here](https://github.com/Tigraine/dotless/blob/master/default.ps1#L87) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx)

OR

- use some tool like [SmartAssembly](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) (commercial)
  it can embed and merge among other things (no need to change your source code)

OR

- [code that yourself in less than 10 lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/microsoft_press/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition) (free but minimal source code change)
  mark all needed dependencies as "embedded resource" - this way they are included in the EXE file... you need to setup an [`AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve) handler which at runtime reads from Resources and returns the needed DLLs to the .NET runtime...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of Jeffrey Richter's solution of embedding assemblies! See my answer mentioning [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/) for a tool that combines this with injecting the necessary code.

Comment: Going ahead with .NET 5.0, [ILRepack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ILRepack/) is the replacement of ILMerge.

Answer (score 31):

A great tool to include referenced assemblies as embedded resources is [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/) (a [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/) add-in). The author Simon Kropp describes it as follows:

> [...] a combination of two methods:
>
> - Jeffrey Richter's suggestion of [using embedded resources as a method of merging
>     assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx)
> - Einar Egilsson's suggestion [using cecil to create module initializers](http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2009/12/16/module-initializers-in-csharp/)

The result is a super simple solution which merely requires to fetch [Costura.Fody](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Costura.Fody) from NuGet.

Features:

- Including debug symbols
- Compression of embedded assemblies
- Including/excluding specific assemblies
- Others (see [Readme](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/blob/master/README.md))

Comment: OMG Costura.Fody is the right answer.  Installed the package from nuget, rebuilt the project and now I have a standalone EXE  AWESOME!!

Comment: I can't believe how easy it is. Just install packages from nuget and your are done.

Comment: I'm using Costura.Fody as well.  It's trivial to setup and dead easy to include NuGet packages as resources.  Get project.

Comment: Is it possible to not lump all assemblies into the main executable but group them as DLLs such as Gui.dll assembly for all GUI related stuff etc?

Comment: @user3700562, this technique does not create new assemblies but rather embeds one or more referenced assemblies into an existing one.

Comment: Great solution! I use it since a year and had no problem. But please note it only includes assemblies referenced by your top project. If your app reference another project which references a third party assembly you need to add it to your top level project.

Answer (score 30):

The tool you are looking for is called [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge) .
It is a command line tool and can be used like this:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:MyApp.exe 
        MyExe.exe ServiceStack.dll ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll  ServiceStack.Text.dll
```

There is also an article that describes how to include ILMerge into your VS project setup [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx)

Comment: Hi, can I add external resource (file/image) into executable?

Comment: @EmdadulSawon maybe you can include them as resources in one of your libs?

Answer (score 7):

Try [ILMerge-GUI, the .NET merger](https://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/).
It's a GUI based `Ilmerge` which avoids all command line work.

Comment: Codeplex is shutting down, so here is the moved project link:
https://bitbucket.org/wvd-vegt/ilmergegui

Answer (score 5):

If you have WPF dependencies your options may be more limited..... ILMerge doesn't appear to deal with these. Costura.Fody (as mentioned by Codefox above) worked perfectly for us however and took about 5 minutes to get going... a very good experience.

Install with Nuget (selecting the correct default project in the Package Manager Console).

It merges the all DLLs marked "Copy Local" = true and produces a merged .EXE (alongside the standard output, most of which is now not necessary) which is also compressed. This can then be used standalone.

The license is MIT as so you can modify/distribute as required.

https://github.com/Fody/Costura/

Answer (score 5):

.net core 3 introduces two new options in the project configuration, called single file publish and trimming.

You can find more details on docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#compiledeploy), project configuration copied here for reference.

1. Project Configuration:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
      <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
      <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

2. Using CLI:

```
    dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
    dotnet publish -r <rid> -c Release
```

It is fully supported to combine the two options together to get a trimmed single assembly for your application.

Comment: This does not give you are single assembly. It simply compresses your files into a zip archive and then unpacks it to a user-folder when you try to run the application.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [ServiceStack.Gap](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap) project which shows several examples of howto ILMerge ServiceStack into a single cross-platform **.exe**.

ServiceStack also includes a number of other features that's particularly well suited for these creating embedded apps where it:

- Allows your services to be self-hosted using .NET's HTTP Listener
- Supports pre-compiled Razor Views
- Supports Embedded Resources
- Supports an embedded database in Sqlite and OrmLite
- Can be ILMerged into a single .exe