# Combine a portable library dll with a Windows Phone dll or a WinRT dll

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I have the following solution :

- A portable library (targetting both WP and WinRT)
- A Windows Phone library (referencing the portable one)
- A Windows RT library (referencing the portable one)

I'm wondering if :

1) Is it possible to combine the portable library with the Windows Phone one, in order to have only one DLL (and do the same with the Windows RT and portable library) ?

2) Is there a way to have a partial class that exists in the portable library and in a platform-specific library ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried looking at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one

Comment: I still want a dll (but one instead of two).

Answer (score 0):

Partial class definitions must be within the same assembly.

As stated in the MSDN docs:
"All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules."
found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: That's what I read and was afraid of. However, if I can combine a portable lib with the platform-specific one, it would also solve the problem.