# Too many references Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio

We have 20 generic solutions dll that we reference in every single project, is it possible to create a single solution and add all references to this new solution. Then use this new solution DLL and reference in other projects.

I am using VS 2012. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also merge the 20 solution assemblies to a single assembly like described here:

[Stackoverflow: How to merge multiple assemblies into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one)

I think using ILMerge is a good way:

[ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)