# Does installutil.exe know how to find external DLLs referenced in the project?

Tags: c#, installutil

I am trying to use installutil.exe to install a windows service. I had it working but but then I added some external DLLs to the project, and now the install is failing. `Copy local` is set to true.  The external DLLs are in various folders beneath my Program Files folder.  I'm opening the CMD window as Administrator.

Where would the catch code be placed to get the `LoaderExceptions` property? In the installer class?

```
          catch (System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
            {

           }
```

Here's the first part of the error:

```
An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the
   C:\Users\foo\My Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ReminderService\ReminderSer
vice\obj\Debug\reminderservice.exe assembly.
The inner exception System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was 
thrown with the following error message: Unable to load one or more of 
the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..
```

Comment: do yourself a favor ant try to merge the dll files into one.. that would save you some troubles... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one

Comment: "Various folders", that can't come to a good end.  Never mess with DLL Hell.

Comment: These are commercial third-party libraries (without source code) that get installed by their installers into folders beneath the Program Files folders. Is this "merging" using ILMerge perfectly transparent? Those DLLs have no idea they've been merged?