# How can I hide (dll) references from a dll project in .NET?

Tags: c#, dll, reference, server, hide

I tried using a server that gives me a DLL which I can use to make a game server code(in a dll project), upload it and let them host the game for me, but here's my problem:
I used an extra dll reference (in addition to their dll reference) when I made the game server code and when I tried to upload it, it said that I can only use *their* dll. So my question is, how can I hide the extra reference I used?

EDIT: I'll try to merge it or something. If it doesn't work that's it. Question closed. Thanks!

Comment: If you *hide* it,(if you could) it won't be loaded, which probably makes your code useless.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one. But whether it is what you need is difficult to say.

Comment: So there isn't a way to 'hide' it and still use it? I just need to bypass their check. EDIT: Eugene Podskal: That might work. I'll try it in a second.

Comment: No, you might try the ILMerge route provided by @EugenePodskal but it is  extremely fragile and won't support everything, which you only find out at runtime.

Comment: is their dll is written in .net then download something like JetBrains .net Peek and try to de-compile it and see what their Edit function is doing

Comment: @MethodMan It gets checked on the website.

Answer (score 0):

If their service requires you to only use their DLL. Then they are serious when they say only use their DLL. They probably did this to avoid complications in some form or another. The only thing I could think of is combining the DLL's together with mkbundle.

```
mkbundle -o Name.dll targetOne.dll targetTwo.dll
```

This will create static copies of the DLL's inside of the Name.dll. However im sure they would have a system to check for this.