# Embed UI DLL into VB.net executable, so user don't need the DLL

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program in VB.net and I need an easy way to take an external UI DLL (Bunifu) and embed it into my project.

So that the user don't have to have the .DLL in the same folder as the executable file.
How do I achieve this as simple as possible?

Comment: This is a C# example, but it looks like it may point the way: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple assemblies into one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one)

Comment: @rskar Thank you I got it working!

Comment: @Raven You're welcome!