# Compress/pack multiple files into 1

Tags: c#

I have created a program, But i don't want the people who start it have access over the files inside. Is there a way to make 10 files pack into 1 `.exe` file?
the `.exe` file is already chosen
I have tried using winrar but u have access to the files there. I have also tried iexpress but for some reason the program doesn't have access to the files inside
So when i start the `.exe` file it is able to use all the other files but not the user.

Comment: You can use some sort of exe encryption, or obfuscation tool.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one

Comment: on smart assembly how do i pick multiple files? @JayV

Comment: @BillyJohnson My apologies, but I have never used Smart Assembly. Colleagues have used ILMerge in the past and they say it works well. Their goal was to only distribute a single file (the .exe) instead of multiple files.

Comment: @JayV what is the easiest approach? , ilmerge seem to work but a little bit hard.

Comment: @BillyJohnson For us, ILMerge was executed from a Batch file. Once setup, simple to use. Easiest is too subjective to answer. It can only be what works for you.

Comment: Why exactly do you don’t want to have the people access over the files inside. Just packing them into one file won’t help a lot, if somebody is actually interested, using obfuscation or exe encryption might help a bit, but will lead to harder support in case of errors. Is it about protecting passwords or more about protecting intellectual property?

Comment: Nothing is going to be 100% full-proof, all you can do is add some added complexity. If the files are that sensitive, storing them within the .exe is probably not a good idea.