# Make Visual Studio Output to single exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

when building my project (WPF), VisualStudio outputs the exe along with all dlls for the project.

[image: List of dlls]

Which, in itself, is a good thing. I on the other hand have just a really small application written and I'd like to just give this exe to my friends so they double click it and voilá.
Is there any way to force VS to "package" all that output into one single executable? Like, when you download an exe, open it and there's your program?

Cheers

Comment: I used SmartAssembly for this.

Comment: @ДмитрийШулицкий yeah, not gonna spend $850 on a simple project... And the 14d trial wouldn't be suitable, I will have to update and "redistribute" this thing for several weeks.

Comment: May be bundle with an installer packager or even self-extracting zip executable file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple assemblies into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one)

Comment: Yep, that's a duplicate. I'm sorry, I have not found this on my inital search.

Comment: Also, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable

Comment: This happened because you have a dependency on a .NETStandard library, you get a copy of all the .netstandard glue as well.  Change the project's framework target to 4.7.1 or higher or use an older version of the library that still targets the full framework instead of .netstandard.