# Removing DLLs from Release/Debug folder in VS build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, configuration

I am not too familiar with visual studios. So I am trying to build an executable for my solution in visual studios but without all of the DLL's present.

When I select the Release configuration and do a clean and rebuild I see the ***bin/Release*** folder with my executable with associated DLL's. Is there a way to have a Release built without all of the DLL's present in ***bin/Release*** folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple assemblies into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077570/how-to-merge-multiple-assemblies-into-one)

Comment: By setting "Copy local" property of reference to false?

Comment: @Selvin okay so I saw a how-to for that but it did not work. The DLL's were still there. Do I need to restart visual studio's?

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to remove them? If the assemblies (aka DLLs) are in the output folder, that means they are being referenced directly or indirectly by your application so they are probably needed.

Comment: @RuiJarimba I really just wanted to know if it is possible and why are still there when I did the "Copy local" change. I believe I understand now.

Comment: Don't remove them unless you're 100% sure these are not needed, otherwise your application will not work properly.

Comment: @RuiJarimba Ok thanks