# How to package dlls in the compiled executable of a C# project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, executable, packaging

I have developed a relatively small windows form application using Visual Studio 2010.

When I build a release version of the application I find the executable in bin/release/ along with a bunch of dll files that are required to it's functionning.

My question is the following:

Is there a way for visual studio to compile the application such that the dll files are "packaged" (I think that is the term?) within the executable so that I could distribute the program as a single .exe file?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I merge multiple .net assemblies into a single assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829531/how-do-i-merge-multiple-net-assemblies-into-a-single-assembly)

Comment: @JonSkeet I read through that thread, my question is different in that I want to know if there is some settings I can change within visual studio to do that automatically upon compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ILMERGE it may use to merge native dll
[ILMERGE](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge)

Comment: This link no longer exists

Comment: updated new link :)

Answer (score 0):

Create new setup and deployment project

Create new project in vs2010
**File -> New -> Project
a windows will appear
select other project Types --> Setup and Deployment
and select Installshield or visual studio installer -- your choice.**
refer msdn about setup and deployment
it will create Distributable executable.

Comment: Thank you but I am not looking to produce an installer for the application. I just want an install-less executable that contains it's own dll dependencies.