# Hide Assemblies from third party

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have two public libraries called **SimpleNetLib** and **ORMLib** (they can be used indepentent from each other), so i am creating a new one that implements the last two called **ORMNetLib.** Thing is i want to hide the two assemblies SimpleNetLib and ORMLib from the user, so the user can only view the implementation of the new lib.

I dont know how to do this, i am using VS2015 and here is a pic of my current solution:

**PD:** ORMLib and SimpleNetLib have marked ORMNetLib as a friendly assembly, so i can implement internal classes.

[image]

Comment: you may merge these assemblies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829531/how-do-i-merge-multiple-net-assemblies-into-a-single-assembly

Comment: that wouldn't still expose the ORMLib and SimpleNetLib implementation to the user?

Comment: There's no way *not to* expose the implementation to the user. Not even in native code. Eventually, the code has to execute somewhere. Why do you care about whether it's exposed or not?

Comment: I dont like to confuse the user, the ORMNetLib override most of the ORMLib project functionalities, the namespaces and functions got almost the same names (with just the prefix "Net" added), i guess it could confuse the user if it looks into the ORMLib implementation and confuse the classes

PD: And i ment from VS intellisense (i know he could actually reverse the assembly and look for the implementation)