# Decoupling: Unable to implement indirect referencing

Tags: vb.net

There are three parts to my code A, B, C. B is a class library which references A which is also a class library. In A, a class `MathOperations` is defined which contains a function `ADD`. The part B has a class `Factory` which in-turn has a function `createMathsObject` which returns an object of `MathOperations` type. The part C refers to B. I can do away with part B and create the object of `MathOperations` type in part C and make C reference A directly where that class is defined. However I am trying to see how I can de-couple sections of the code, in this case A and C.I give the code for each of the three parts A, B and C. The error message that I get is mentioned later for which I need your help.

Part A: Class Library - Named as *MathLibrary.dll*

```
Public Class MathOperations
    Function ADD(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
        Return (a + b)
    End Function
End Class
```

Part B: Class Library - Named as *FactoryMathsLibrary.dll* which references *MathLibrary.dll*

```
Imports MathLibrary
Public Class Factory
    Shared Function createMathsObject() As MathOperations
        Return New MathOperations()
    End Function
End Class
```

Part C: Exe file - which references *FactoryMathsLibrary.dll*

```
Imports FactoryMathsLibrary
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a, b As Integer
        Dim m As Object = Factory.createMathsObject() 'Error comes here
        Console.Write("Enter 1st value: ")
        a = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Enter 2nd value: ")
        b = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("a + b = {0}", m.ADD(a, b))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

I was under the impression that since C references B and B references A, everything would be fine. But I am getting an error in the line `Dim m As Object = Factory.createMathsObject()`. The error message is as follows: Can someone pls help with the reason behind the error and the solution??

[image: Error message]

Comment: _"C references B and B references A"_ This means that B has direct access to A and C has direct access to B, so B can uses types of A on behalf of C but C cannot access them directly. If you need to access them directly (as in the example above), then A must also reference C.

Comment: @41686d6564 *"then **C** must also reference to A"* **\*** **?**

Comment: @GiorgosXou Yes, thanks for spotting the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I did exactly what you did**, in your exe-project you haven't added reference to "MathLibrary.dll". You can't include a library that references to another library without including that second library in your exe-project too *[(Unless you merge them into one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829535/11465149)*! if you won't include it too, you will have exactly the issue that you are having.

**And so,** you only have to add reference to "FactoryMathsLibrary.dll" **and to "MathLibrary.dll"**
`Project > project_name Properties... > References > Add... > MathLibrary.dll > OK`

#### ❌ Without reference

[image]

#### ✔️ With reference

[image]